# show selected/highlighted Text on User/Other screen

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I Got project in which the client wants me to develop a web application on asp.net MVC in which the client wants something that is new to me so I need your help.

So my client wants a web application in which there is instructor and instructors have some students. so there are many instructors and many students.

So he wants that both instructor and user both log in at the same time from there own separate system/pc and when the instructor open any book/pdf same book/pdf automatically open on the student screen and when the instructor goes to specific page same page open on the student screen and when the instructor highlight/select the word or line same line or word highlight at the student screen.

Hope you understand my problem. I need some reference or guidance because I never work on such thing thanks

Comment: This not consider an answer, but just my personal suggestion.
You might need to have SignalR in your solution in order to have the highlight thingy work. By calling ajax when the instructor clicking/highlighting on the book(which might be in html format).

Signal R - Allows server code to send asynchronous notifications to client-side web applications

Comment: Do you have any tutorial or any video or any type of website where I get the basic concept

Comment: The signal R documentation with javascript client is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client